# How to encourage our 2.5-year-old to tell us when he needs to go to the potty?

Tags: toddler, communication, potty-training, motivation

Our son is 2.5 years old. We have been potty training him since his 2nd birthday. It's been a long haul but we're getting there.

When he is outside in his underwear he knows when he needs to go pee and will pull down his underwear and go. We don't have to remind him. But while he is inside playing, he will have accidents and we have to take him every 1-1.5 hours. If not, he will have an accident. He will not tell us he needs to go while being inside. I know he knows when he needs to go since he does it outside but not inside.

Not sure what to do. Is he being lazy? What can I do to encourage him to tell us while being inside?

Answer (score 1):

He's 2.5 . He's learning still.

My own son had the same kind of issue with #2, but kept having accidents until we took him to a drive in theater. The magic moment happened when we were a good 1/4 mile from the faciltities, so he had to walk across the field in his mess before we could change him. About halfway there he announced "never again", and he never had another accident (unless he was sick).

Answer (score 1):

I know, that potty training is quite common (and I do not believe, that it's necessarily harmful), but I doubt that it's necessary or worthwhile. There are people arguing that **it's mostly a matter of brain development** and - while I have no formal education in this field - I think this is reasonable.

My daughter is 3 years 3 months old and we basically never did potty train her. We made offerings to her (we do not have a potty, but a family seat on the toilet with another smaller seat), but using diapers until she's ready was quite fine for us. Recently - about maybe 2 months ago - **she decided** that she did not want the diapers anymore and it worked (*almost*) perfectly. Of course we've had some accidents, but most of the time (99%-ish) she tells that she has to pee and either we will go to the toilet with her, or she will go alone. About two weeks later she decided to leave away the diaper at night, too. We did not have a single incident.

Defecation is not that easy yet, but at least she will tell us that she needs a diaper for and we'll remove it when she's done.

**Long story short:** Give him the time he needs and do not try to force things. Learning how to do these thnigs is a natural urge and when the time has come he will eventually learn.